# Почему не работает ng-click? Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, ng-click

```
<td header-class="'w25p'" ng-click="table.redirect($event)" data-title="'Дата платежа/на балансе'" sortable="'dateOfPayment'">
```

где `table` имя контроллера

```
  .controller('TableCtrl', ['$http', 'NgTableParams', 'accountNumber', '$element', '$scope',  
    function ($http, NgTableParams, accountNumber, $element, $scope){
      function redirect($event){
        console.log('клик');
      }
      redirect($event);
      // просто для начала хочу вывести в консоль клик.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не добавили метод в контроллер, у вас только ни к чему не привязанная функция.

Внутри контроллера напишите:

```
this.redirect = redirect;

function redirect($event){
  console.log('клик');
}
```

Рабочий пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

Ctrl.$inject = [];
function Ctrl() {
  this.click = click;

  function click() {
    console.log('click');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl as c">
  <button ng-click="c.click()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Теперь пишет redirect is not defined

Comment: Вы же не вместо функции это написали?

Comment: нет, не вместо функции